# SQL statement with multiple DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

The query that I'm attempting to build will use the following columns in **tableA**:

- name
- description

The query should provide the following filters:

- Select names from **tableA** which are not duplicates
- Select only the names which do not have duplicate descriptions
- Select descriptions which do not contain the strings: "Any" or "Deleted"
- Order by name

Here's my current statement which gives me everything except for the duplicate descriptions. How can I add this to my current statement?

> SELECT
>
> ```
>  DISTINCT name FROM tableA
>
>  WHERE description NOT LIKE 'Any%'
>
>  AND description NOT LIKE 'Deleted%'
> ```
>
> ORDER BY name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using a self-join.
Use the left-side table to filter descriptions that start with "Any" or "Deleted".  Since you want to eliminate rows with duplicate descriptions, you only select results where a matching row on the right side with the same description but a different name could not be found:

```
SELECT
    leftSide.name,
    leftSide.description
FROM
    tableA as leftSide
    LEFT JOIN tableA as rightSide ON (
        leftSide.description = rightSide.description AND
        leftSide.name <> rightSide.name
    )
WHERE
    rightSide.description IS NULL AND
    leftSide.description NOT LIKE 'Any%' AND
    leftSide.description NOT LIKE 'Deleted%'
GROUP BY
    leftSide.name, leftSide.description
ORDER BY
    leftSide.name
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be returning what I'm looking for. Here's a SQL fiddle. I should have NO duplicates anywhere in the table. No duplicate names, no duplicate descriptions. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59297/1

Comment: Thanks, the SQL Fiddle helped me zero in on my typing mistakes!

Comment: Haha, no problem. Let me try out your most recent one. This might work. Is there a way for the FIRST distinct one to be kept instead of the second? In the fiddle, how can I get the FIRST "Eng" row to return instead of that second one?

Comment: Since there's no way to reliably predict that duplicates in name will appear in the first, some middle, or the last position, consider removing the `GROUP BY name` part of the clause.  That way, you'll see rows with unique descriptions that have the same name.

Comment: Actually, the first "Eng" row was disqualified because it had the same description as "Eng, General".

Comment: But is there a way to save "Eng" instead? And hmm, the above code is still not working. It seems to work in the fiddle just fine, but on my data it's not. I'll get back to you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20288/discussion-between-danny-and-jon)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT

 DISTINCT name FROM tableA

 WHERE description NOT LIKE 'Any%','Deleted%'

ORDER BY name
```

Comment: from the select statement you posted, only one field "name" was shown.

Answer (score 0):

Will this be the solution you are looking for?

Reference: [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd670/2)

Query:

```
select distinct name, des
from data
where des not like '%any%'
and des not like '%delete%'
order by name ASC;
```

Results:

```
NAME    DES

mary    yeah all or none
tim     yeah all or none
you     did you see he is in
```

Comment: John should not show up twice. I want only distinct names and distinct descriptions.

Comment: Ahh, still not there. Only one of mary and tim should show up, since the description is duplicated. Maybe this would be a better description. I have a table of jobs (external...I didn't make it, sot his is my cleaning process). Each job has a description. Some jobs are duplicate names and have different descriptions. Some have different names, but duplicate descriptions.

Comment: Basically I want NO duplicates across BOTH columns. I don't want to see two of the same job title, and I don't want to see two of the same description.

Comment: I noticed that now :) you want distinct on multiple varchar fields. If you had an int field, that makes it easier, since there's varchar this question gets interesting. +1 for that ;)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT t.name
FROM tableA AS t
GROUP BY t.name
HAVING COUNT(*)=1 AND t.description NOT LIKE 'Any%' AND t.description NOT LIKE 'Deleted%'
ORDER BY t.name;